# Applying own functions

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply my own function. Below you can see the data and function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
data_test = { 
            'sales_2017': [100,0,300,0,200], 
            'profit_2017': [20,0,30,50,0],             
           }
    
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data_test, columns = ['sales_2017','profit_2017','sales_2018','profit_2018'])
    
df['effective']= df['profit_2017']/df['sales_2017']
    
df

# Create distribution table
conditions = [
(df['effective'] == 0),
(df['effective'] > 0.1) & (df['effective'] < 0.20),
(df['effective'] > 0.20),
(df['effective'] == "NaN"),
(df['effective'] == "inf"),
]
values = ['Equal to zero','Between 0.1 and 0.2', 'Above 0.2', 'Equal to NaN', "Equal to infinity"]

df['effective_range'] = np.select(conditions, values)

distribution_table = df.groupby('effective_range').agg(count=('effective_range','count'))
```

So main idea here is to create a distribution table in accordance with this condtions 'Equal to zero','Between 0.1 and 0.2', 'Above 0.2', 'Equal to NaN', "Equal to infinity".

My set have values with `'Nan'` and also with `'inf'` and this causes a problem with final table and below you can see pic.

[image]

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and to have a table like a table below?

effective_range        count
Equal to zero       1
Between 0.1 and 0.2     0
Above 0.2               1
Equal to NaN            1
Equal to infinity       1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and [`numpy.isinf`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html) methods:

```
# Create distribution table
conditions = [
(df['effective'] == 0),
(df['effective'] > 0.1) & (df['effective'] < 0.20),
(df['effective'] > 0.20),
(df['effective'].isna()),
(np.isinf(df['effective'])),
]
values = ['Equal to zero','Between 0.1 and 0.2', 'Above 0.2', 
          'Equal to NaN', "Equal to infinity"]

df['effective_range'] = np.select(conditions, values)

distribution_table = df.groupby('effective_range').agg(count=('effective_range','count'))
print (distribution_table)

                 count
effective_range       
0                    2
Above 0.2            1
Equal to NaN         1
Equal to zero        1
```